# Tensorflow reset or clear collection

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

In tensorflow, I find the API `tf.add_to_collcetion` to add some value to collection like code bellow.

```
def accuracy_rate(logits, labels):
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)
    # Return the accuracy of true entries.
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))
    return accuracy 
with tf.Session() as sess:
    logits, labels = ...
    accuracy = accuracy_rate(logits, labels)
    tf.add_to_collection('total_accuracy', sess.run(accuracy))
```

What I can't find in the API is that, how can I clear all values that I've already stored in one collection?

Comment: I know you have found an alternative solution, but you may also consider `tf.get_default_graph().clear_collection('total_accuracy')` for this purpose. Since a collection also contains `variables`, `trainable_variables` and `train_op`, it's recommanded to delete values by key.

Comment: @JohnHany: This seems to be a better way than all the answers here. Although it is quite old, you can consider adding it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tf.get_collection_ref` to get a mutable reference to the collection which you can clear (it's just a python list).

Comment: Did you mean that I can clear the values in the collection？

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for?

```
In [2]: import tensorflow as tf
In [3]: w = tf.Variable([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [3,1,5], [4,1,7]], collections=[tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS, tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES], dtype=tf.float32)
In [4]: params = tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS)
In [5]: del params[:]
In [6]: tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS)                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[6]: []
In [10]: params = tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
In [11]: params
Out[11]: [<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(5, 3) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Answer (score -2):

Find an alternative solution, using different tf.Graph().